# Reading integers and getting the answer + 10

Tags: java, input, stream

I have written a readInt() method to read integers from System.in but for some reason every integer returned is off by 10. This is regardless of whether the number is one or several digits and it is confusing me to no end. My code is below, where have I gone wrong?

```
/**
 * @return The next integer read from the Input Stream
 */
public static int readInt() throws IOException {
    BufferedInputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(System.in);
    char c = (char) in.read();
    int num = 0, cNum = Character.getNumericValue(c);

    //Checks that the current value of c is in fact a single digit number (as it must be to be a char and an int)
    while (cNum > -1 && cNum < 10) {
        num = num * 10 + cNum;

        c = (char) in.read();
        cNum = Character.getNumericValue(c);
    }

    //If no number has been read, keep reading until one is read
    if (num == 0 && c != '0') {
        return readInt();
    }

    System.out.print(num + '\n');
    return num;
}
```

**EXAMPLE I/O:**

INPUT (I): 1 - OUTPUT (O): 11

I: 2 - O: 12

I: 3 - O: 13

I: 5 - O: 15

I: 10 - O: 20

I: 99 - O: 109

I: 100 - O: 110

Comment: what do you mean by `off by 10` can you add demo input output values

Comment: I've added examples underneath

Comment: I guess you are asking about these two cases `20 109`

Comment: They are all off by 10. Input 1: you get get 11. Input 99: you get 109.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Collin,
I hope you are fine.

I took a look at your code and tested it.
Apparently, the '\n' is the cause of your problem, because when I deleted it the result was fine.

if you want to start a new line, replace '\n' with "\n" (double quotes not single quotes).
I hope my answer did help :)

Answer (score 6):

When you add a character to an integer it does integer arithmetic.

So

```
 x + '\n'
```

is the same as

```
 x + 10
```

because `(int) '\n'` is `10`

What you intended is

```
 x + "\n"
```

which does strings arithmetic

But a simpler/more efficient solution is

```
 System.out.println(x);
```